# The Makefile in my c program doesn't work in CMD but fine in Linux terminal

Tags: c, gcc, makefile

I installed MinGW and i can type in CMD "gcc -o FileName main.c header.h" fine
but when i type in console "make" it tells me it doesn't know that command. Although i have a file called "Makefile" with no extenstion. Whats wrong?

Comment: Do you have `make` installed? If not, maybe you need to. It's also worth noting that `mingw` is a really second-rate experience compared to [Windows Subsystem for Linux (WSL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/about) that's available now.

Comment: On an unrelated note: You should generally not be building your header files. They will be included into your source files (forming a [*translation unit*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Translation_unit_(programming))) automatically by the `#include` preprocessor directive. You don't need to provide the header files as arguments to `gcc` for that inclusion to work.

Comment: If make is installed, is it on the PATH? If you have the which command installed, you could try 'which make'

Answer (score 0):

MinGW has a renamed `make`, try `mingw32-make`.

You might like to copy it with the more common name in the same directory.